# Defaulting typeclass instances in Haskell and PureScript

Tags: haskell, typeclass, purescript

I have a simple class that has an instance for `Int` and `[]`/`Array` in Haskell/PureScript:

HS:

```
class C c where f :: c -> c
instance C Int where f x = x
instance C c => C [c] where f l = map f l
```

PS:

```
class C c where f :: c -> c
instance intC :: C Int where f x = x
instance arrC :: C c => C (Array c) where f l = map f l
```

In both representations the value of `f []` is `[]` – regardless of the instantiation of the type `c`. However, when I write

```
f []
```

I get an ambiguity error:

HS:

```
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘f’
      prevents the constraint ‘(C a0)’ from being solved.
```

PS:

```
  The inferred type
    forall t4. C t4 => Boolean
  has type variables which are not determined by those mentioned in the body of the type:
    t4 could not be determined
```

Understandable; there is indeed an ambiguity which confuses the compiler during the class dictionary assignment. However, in this particular case it should not be a problem, as the only case where `c` is undetermined is when the list is empty, so when the result is known.

Is it possible to convince the compiler to default the unset typevars to something specific? I would like to automatically solve ambiguities with that class by instantiating them with `Int`, for example. I know that it already happens with the `Num` class: I even sometimes get a warning that "`2137` was defaulted to be an `Integer`" in Haskell. Asking about both languages, I am aware that the answers might be slightly different.

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining a practical situation where this would be necessary. Can you expand your examples a bit to show why you would need this?

Comment: The case is quite specific, I don't think it would clarify the matter of the question. I am writing an Erlang-to-Purescript transpiler (https://github.com/erlscripten) where I represent Erlang terms via some ADT. I want to have convenient way of turning arbitrary PS expressions into that, so I have a class ToErlang with toErlang :: a -> ErlangTerm method. There is an instance of Arrays of ToErlangs for it, but due to the problem above I need to specify the types of empty arrays which is quite annoying. I was curious if it could be done in some (in)sane way

Comment: I would just have an `emptyArray :: ErlangTerm`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sort of option.

```hs
data CList a where
  CNil :: CList a
  CCons :: C a => a -> CList a -> CList a

instance C (CList a) where
  f CNil = CNil
  f (CCons x xs) = CCons (f x) (f xs)
```

For a plain list, the best I can think of is to enable `ExtendedDefaultRules` and define

```hs
instance C () where
  f ~() = ()
```

I believe this should default your `[]` to `[] :: [()]` and do the right thing.